# How can i convert column into days in csv having string values in years , months , weeks using Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have done a try with python as below :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("master_list.csv", usecols = ['Duration'])
#month manipulation starts
df[df['Duration'].fillna('').str.contains('Months') & df['Duration'].fillna('').str.len().gt(0)]
df["Duration"] = df["Duration"].str.replace("\sMonths", "")
df['Duration'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Duration'], errors='coerce').fillna(0).astype(float)
df['Duration'] *= 30.436875
#month manipulation end
df[df['Duration'].fillna('').str.contains('Weeks') & df['Duration'].fillna('').str.len().gt(0)]
df["Duration"] = df["Duration"].str.replace("\sWeeks", "")
#df['Duration'] *= 30.436875

print(df)
```

```
Sample_Data = ["7 Months","1 Year","8 Weeks","3 Days"]
Expected Output = ["210 Days","365 Days","56 Days","3 Days"]
```

Comment: Can you add expected output from sample data?

Comment: hmmm, can you add data like text to question with expected ouput?

Comment: I already have posted expected output . I want the "Duration" column in csv in days , currently it is in all formats years , months , weeks .

Comment: I cannot see data like text.

Comment: I cannot see exactly what need in ouput - how many days for it. I think numbers, not description

Comment: I want whole column in days
For example : if the value in column is 1 month then convert it to 30 days
if the value in column is 2 years then convert it to 730 days
if the value in column is 7 weeks then convert it to 49 days 
so on..... for all the values .

Comment: `"expected ouput"` means some table with values, not description. ie `example_data=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]` `expected_output=[[101,102,103],[104,105,106]]` - so we can use it for tests.

Comment: see module [dateparser](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) - it seems it can convert `"7 Months","1 Year","8 Weeks","3 Days"` to `datetime` and later you can convert it to days.

Answer (score 0):

Module [dateparser](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) can parse text with `weeks`,`years`, `months`, `days`, etc.

```
import dateparser
import datetime

sample_data = ["7 Months","1 Year","8 Weeks","3 Days"]

today = datetime.datetime.now()

for item in sample_data:
    result = dateparser.parse(item)
    diff = today.date() - result.date()
    print(item, '|', diff.days)
```

Result:

```
7 Months | 212
1 Year | 365
8 Weeks | 56
3 Days | 3
```